# Does fake Input Affect GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: c++, keyboard

I'm trying to detect fake user input, in other words, not coming from the actual keyboard, from the hand of the user, but emulated with `SendInput` or  `SendMessage` etc.

MSDN teaches you that `GetAsyncKeyState` gets the physical key state, but other answers say `SendInput` looks like a legitimate input to the target program.

Does `SendInput` affect `GetAsyncKeyState`? and If not, is it reliable to check the key state while processing the input queue, and discard non legit input by checking if the key is really down?